# Find the length of longest increasing subsequence C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, function

Please help me solve this problem, when input `10` and  `1 2 3 1 2 3 3 4 5 6`

Output should be `4` but it's `6`.

In all other tests, the program is working well.

For Example:

```
Input: 1   -10
Output: 1

Input: 2   123 123
Output: 1

Input: 2   -1245 234
Output: 2

Input: 5   1 2 3 -1 -20
Output: 3

Input: 5   1 1 2 3 1
Output: 3

Input: 5   0 0 0 1 10000
Output: 3
```

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int subsequence(int arr[], int n) {

 int* length = new int[n];
 int max_length = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { 
       if (arr[j] < arr[i] && length[j] > length[i])
          length[i] = length[j];
    }
        length[i]++; 
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    max_length = max(max_length, length[i]);
 }
 delete [] length;

      return max_length;
}
int main() {
  int n;
      cin >> n;
  int* arr = new int[n];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      cin >> arr[i];
  }
      cout << subsequence(arr, n);

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: The longest increasing subsequence of  `1 2 3 1 2 3 3 4 5 6` is `1 2 3 4 5 6`, and its length is `6`. It seems that your program returns the correct answer.

Comment: in my tests true answer is 4. i dont now why

Comment: Looks like the test is wrong then, because in this example the longest increasing subsequence can hardly be more obvious.

Comment: probably doesn't consider repeating numbers

Comment: @ThomasSablik you're mistaking substring (or subarray) with subsequence. The longest increasing substring (or subarray) has length 4, but the longest increasing subsequence has length 6. The input/output examples make a great job at keeping the notion ambiguous since all examples have similar results for both longest substring and subsequence.

Comment: are you looking for contiguous subsecquences? Adding the task description to the question would help to clarify that

Comment: @idclev463035818 a contiguous subsequence is called a substring. Cf definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence)

Comment: @Vardan: The output of "2 123 123", shouldn't that be 2 instead of 1? By the way, it might be a good idea to explain for all cases the subsequence which indeed has the length you are referring to, that might be easier for the people to understand the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Dominique, thoough it's not quite clear by the sample layout, the first value is the number of values to be inputed, so 1 is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `length` array values are unitialized, this will invoke undefined behavior, in your case, by chance, it works, but you should expect that whatever garbage values are in the array will be used as a comparison, to avoid this you should fill it with `0`s.

Then, this piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    max_length = max(max_length, length[i]);   
    std::cout << max_length << " ";    
}
```

This means, broadly speaking, that the `max_length` will increase as long as the next number is larger than the previous, there is no variable reset, both sequences are counted:

```
1 2 3 1 2 3 3 4 5 6  //input sequence

1 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6  //max_length value along the function
^ ^ ^         ^ ^ ^
+ + +         + + +
```

Hence the `6` output.

That said, you wouldn't need such a convoluted piece of code for such a simple task, if you just need to count the max sequence, something along the lines of:

```
int subsequence(int arr[], int n) {

    int max_length = 1; //hold the max_length
    int temp = 1;       //hold the temporary max_length

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if(arr[i + 1] > arr[i]) { 
            temp++;     //if the next value is larger increase temp
            max_length = std::max(max_length, temp); //assign largest temp to max_length
        }
        else{     
            temp = 1;   //otherwise reset temp
        }    
    }
    return max_length;  //return max_length
}
```

Side note:

Since you're using C++, you could upgrade your code to use C++ containers instead of C style arrays, `std::vector` in this case, given the variable size array.

Comment: question asks for subsequence which is not necessarily contiguos, you have answered for subarray

Comment: @DushyantSingh, if you read the question and the comments carefully you will see that this is exactly what the OP wants.